# How to handle redirect request in c#

Tags: c#, .net, postman

I am making a POST API call for a target endpoint which is responding with 302 - Re-direct status code in the response with a "Location" header added along with some cookies.
If I retry the request using the URL provided in the "Location" header by passing cookies found in the request, the API fails.

If I run the API using postman the API works perfectly fine and it doesn't result in 302 redirect status code.

can anyone suggests how to handle the redirect scenario in c#. Also, can anyone help me understanding how POSTMAN handles the API with redirect response.

sample c# code

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;


var apiUrl = "url";
var authorization = "bearer token";
var jsonContent = "json payload";


var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = false,
    CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
};

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, apiUrl);
   
    var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonContent);
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
    request.Content = stringContent;
    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.Send(request);
    printResponse(response);

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently)
    {
        var redirectUrl = response.Headers.Location;
        request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, redirectUrl);

        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
        request.Content = stringContent;
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var cookieCollection = httpClientHandler.CookieContainer.GetAllCookies();
        foreach (Cookie cookie in cookieCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{cookie.Name}={cookie.Value}");
            request.Headers.Add("Cookie", $"{cookie.Name}={cookie.Value}");
        }

        response = client.Send(request);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("StatusCode ::: " + response.StatusCode);
}
```

Thanks and regards,
Suraj Jannu

Comment: The `httpClientHandler` should have `AllowAutoRedirect` set to true.  [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.allowautoredirect?view=net-7.0#system-net-http-httpclienthandler-allowautoredirect) should help.

Comment: I have tried this option and this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

`Cookie` header should be added once with all `Key=Value;` pairs.
Try to replace this:

```cs
foreach (Cookie cookie in cookieCollection)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"{cookie.Name}={cookie.Value}");
  request.Headers.Add("Cookie", $"{cookie.Name}={cookie.Value}");
}
```

with this:

```cs
var cookies = string.Join("; ", cookieCollection.Select(cookie => $"{cookie.Name}={cookie.Value}"));
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookies);
```

Comment: this solution didn't work